# Poker simulation give unrealistic results

Tags: python

So I was trying to find cool stats on poker, and made a simulation. But despites every function working find when tested individually, it is not giving result that can be real. Here is the code :

```
import random
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict


def value_of_hand(cards):
    # This is a function that takes 5 cards and returns the value of the hand
    # It should return a tuple with the name of the hand and the value of the hand
    # Example: Input: 5H 5C 6S 7S KD Output: ('Pair', 2.05)
    # Example: Input: 2C 3S 8S 8D TD Output: ('Pair', 2.08)
    # Example: Input: 2C 3S 8S 8D 8H Output: ('Three of a Kind', 4.08)
    # Example: Input: 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C Output: ('Straight Flush', 6.06)
    
    # Helper function to get the numerical value of the card rank
    def get_card_value(card):
        values = {
            '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, 'T': 10, 'J': 11,
            'Q': 12, 'K': 13, 'A': 14
            }
        return values[card[0]]
    
    # Helper function to check if the hand is a flush
    def is_flush(cards):
        return len(set(card[1] for card in cards)) == 1 and len(cards) == 5
    
    # Helper function to check if the hand is a straight
    def is_straight(cards):
        values = sorted([get_card_value(card) for card in cards])
        return all(values[i] == values[i - 1] + 1 for i in range(1, len(values)))
    
    # Helper function to check for pairs, three of a kind, and four of a kind
    
    def find_multiples(cards):
        ranks = [get_card_value(card) for card in cards]
        rank_counts = defaultdict(int)
        
        for rank in ranks:
            rank_counts[rank] += 1
        
        pairs = []
        three_of_a_kind = None
        four_of_a_kind = None
        
        for rank, count in rank_counts.items():
            if count == 2:
                pairs.append(rank)
            elif count == 3:
                three_of_a_kind = rank
            elif count == 4:
                four_of_a_kind = rank
        
        return pairs, three_of_a_kind, four_of_a_kind
    
    # Sorting the cards based on their values (descending order)
    cards.sort(key=lambda card: get_card_value(card), reverse=True)
    
    # Finding multiples (pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind)
    pairs, three_of_a_kind, four_of_a_kind = find_multiples(cards)
    
    # Checking for flush and straight
    is_flush_hand = is_flush(cards)
    is_straight_hand = is_straight(cards)
    
    # Determining the name and value of the hand
    if is_flush_hand and is_straight_hand:
        # Straight Flush
        name = 'Straight Flush'
        value = 9 + max(get_card_value(cards[0]), get_card_value(cards[4])) / 100.0
    
    elif four_of_a_kind:
        # Four of a Kind
        name = 'Four of a Kind'
        value = 8 + four_of_a_kind / 100.0
    
    elif len(pairs) == 1 and three_of_a_kind:
        # Full House
        name = 'Full House'
        value = 7 + three_of_a_kind / 100.0
    
    elif is_flush_hand:
        # Flush
        name = 'Flush'
        value = 6 + max(get_card_value(card) for card in cards) / 100.0
    
    elif is_straight_hand:
        # Straight
        name = 'Straight'
        value = 5 + max(get_card_value(cards[0]), get_card_value(cards[4])) / 100.0
    
    elif three_of_a_kind:
        # Three of a Kind
        name = 'Three of a Kind'
        value = 4 + three_of_a_kind / 100.0
    
    elif len(pairs) == 2:
        # Two Pair
        name = 'Two Pair'
        value = 3 + max(pairs) / 100.0 + min(pairs) / 10000.0
    
    elif len(pairs) == 1:
        # Pair
        name = 'Pair'
        value = 2 + pairs[0] / 100.0
    
    else:
        # High Card
        name = 'High Card'
        # Assign value based on the highest card
        value = sum(get_card_value(cards[i]) / (100 ** (i+1)) for i in range(5))
    
    return name, value


def main():
    def one_game():
        deck = [rank + suit for rank in '23456789TJQKA' for suit in 'SHDC']
        random.shuffle(deck)
        number_of_players = 2
        player_cards = []
        for i in range(number_of_players):
            player_cards.append([deck.pop(), deck.pop()])
        community_cards = [deck.pop() for i in range(5)]
        player_scores = []
        for i in range(number_of_players):
            # Find the best hand with the player's cards and the community cards
            # First get all combinations of 5 cards from the 7 available cards
            # Then find the best hand from those 5 cards
            combinations = itertools.combinations(player_cards[i] + community_cards, 5)
            best_hand = max([list(combination) for combination in combinations], key=value_of_hand)
            player_scores.append(value_of_hand(best_hand))
            # # Print the player's cards, community cards, and best hand if it is a flush or better
            # if float(player_scores[i][1]) >= 6:
            #   print('Player %d: %s, %s, %s' % (i + 1, str(player_cards[i]), str(community_cards), str(best_hand)))
        winner = player_scores.index(max(player_scores))
        return player_cards, community_cards, player_scores[winner][0], player_scores
    
    # Play 1000 games and get statistics about the winning hands
    player_cards_list, community_cards_list, winning_hand_list, player_scores_list = [], [], [], []
    for i in range(10000):
        player_cards, community_cards, winning_hand, player_scores = one_game()
        player_cards_list.append(player_cards)
        community_cards_list.append(community_cards)
        winning_hand_list.append(winning_hand)
        player_scores_list.append(player_scores)
    
    # Print the statistics
    print('\nProbability of winning with each hand:')
    possible_hands = ['High Card', 'Pair', 'Two Pair', 'Three of a Kind', 'Straight', 'Flush',
                      'Full House', 'Four of a Kind', 'Straight Flush']
    for hand in possible_hands:
        # Get the number of times each hand happened, even if it didn't win
        hand_count = 0
        for player_scores in player_scores_list:
            for player_score in player_scores:
                if player_score[0] == hand:
                    hand_count += 1
        # Get the number of times each hand won
        hand_win_count = winning_hand_list.count(hand)
        try:
            print(
                '{}: {} / {} ({}%)'.format(
                    hand, hand_win_count, hand_count, hand_win_count / hand_count * 100
                    )
                )
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('{}: 0 / 0'.format(hand))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the results :

```
Probability of winning with each hand:
High Card: 665 / 3743 (17.766497461928935%)
Pair: 4056 / 9121 (44.46880824471001%)
Two Pair: 4071 / 5204 (78.228285933897%)
Three of a Kind: 575 / 1062 (54.143126177024484%)
Straight: 628 / 861 (72.93844367015099%)
Flush: 0 / 3 (0.0%)
Full House: 0 / 0
Four of a Kind: 0 / 0
Straight Flush: 5 / 6 (83.33333333333334%)
```

We can see I don't get any Full House, Four of a Kind, and very few Flush, usually none

I tried to test every function individually, and every function seems to work so I have litteraly no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Got curious and checked the propability of a [flush](https://www.thoughtco.com/probability-of-a-flush-3126591) and it seems off. Also, you commented that you play 1000 games but it's 10000 in the loop, even if it's 10000 games it still doesn't add up. 9121 + 3743 is already over 10000, am I missing something here?

Comment: Bug: You're mislabeling `A2345` as high card

Comment: @doneforaiur I am there is 20000 hands in total, because there is 2 players that's why. But yeah the comment is not right

Comment: The calculation for `best_hand` is broken. It counts `Two Pair` as the most valuable card combination, and if you have a `Full House`, you can almost certainly make a `Two Pair` combination given the five community cards. This is why `Full House` almost never shows up: because there's almost always a better hand according to the broken `best_hand` calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: OH!

So your simulation is, sort of, giving realistic results. However, the way you're comparing scores is wrong.

This line:

```
        best_hand = max([list(combination) for combination in combinations], key=value_of_hand)
```

should be:

```
        best_hand = max([list(combination) for combination in combinations], key=lambda h: value_of_hand(h)[1])
```

Your original program counts `Two Pair` as the most valuable hand. (because the name of the hand score comes first, and `Two Pair` is alphabetically last)

The reason I didn't detect this when trimming your program down for testing is that in my stripped down version, you only had one hand possible per game so a broken `best_hand` calculation didn't matter.

---- Original answer below ---

I think that your simulation is actually giving realistic results, for the game that it's playing. (Texas hold-em)

<s>Texas hold-em has an unusually high number of community cards for a poker variant, and that can affect the probabilities.</s>  (EDIT: but it should affect them in the opposite direction for something like "Full House")

To test your program, I modified it to have only one player being dealt five cards of their own (no community cards), and compared the results to the known hand probabilities.

For example, the known probability of getting a full house in a simple five-card is [calculated here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808314/probability-of-getting-a-full-house) as about 0.00144, or about 14.4 times out of 10,000.

I ran your program (modified for only one player and no community cards) 100 times and got a total of 1429 "full house" results. That's pretty close.

Comment: I find it very strange that full house don't happened in over 100 000 games (the bigger number I ran the code with), but yeah it seems to be right

Comment: Yeah, I found the bug. Edited my answer just now.

Comment: `winner = player_scores.index(max(player_scores))` - looks like that line also needs to be fixed to use the appropriate key in 'max'.

Comment: Good catch: that also needs fixing.